# How to link to a LaTeX label within align* environment in Orgmode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, hyperlinks

I am using org mode to write documents with math, and then exporting to latex. Consider an unnumbered align environment with two equations:

```
\begin{align*}
x = 1\\
y = 2
\end{align*}
```

Now, number the second equation using, for example, `\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}`, and then label it:

```
\begin{align*}
x = 1\\
y = 2 \addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}} \label{ref_me}
\end{align*}
```

**Question**: How can I link to `ref_me` in org mode so that:

1. Exporting to latex works
2. The link is clickable within org mode (just like with a [[]] reference)

In other words: how to reference an equation within the align environment so that it works when exported to latex, and so that anyone viewing the org file can click on the link and be taken to the equation.

Thanks   for your help and for your time! :D

Answer (score 1):

org-ref (https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref) can make a link for this, e.g. ref:ref_me.

Comment: Hey John, thanks for the suggestion.  That looks like a good solution, although I was hoping there would be something more simple that could solve this.